# How to display error from comparison statement

Tags: powershell, if-statement, powershell-3.0, comparison-operators

I am trying to get in error message to pop when certain conditions do not match. The information is browsing through a csv file.

My issue is one of my statements work but does not display anything. Here is my condition statement.

```
$spellingerror = $hostid -notin $data."Host ID"
$existsnotopen = $hostid -eq $data."Host ID" -and $_.Status -ne $data.Open

  if ($spellingerror) 
{Write-Host -foregroundcolor Green "Host does not exist"}

  elseif ($existsnotopen)
{Write-Host -foregroundcolor Green "Host exists and is not open"}

  else
   {$data | Sort-Object {[DateTime]$_."Last Modified"} |   Where-Object
   {$_."Host ID" -eq $hostid -and $_."Status" -eq "Open"} | 
   Select -First 1 -ExpandProperty "Last Modified"}
```

> this is the issue

```
elseif ($existsnotopen)
{Write-Host -foregroundcolor Green "Host exists and is not open"}
```

it will not output Host exists and is not open, I do not get an error message.

`$hosted` is a string so I see why I cant use `-eq`. I changed it to `-match`.
I used `$data."Host ID"` because I wanted it to search the whole spreadsheet like I did in `-notin $data."Host ID"`. I tried using what you tried because my status are either "Open" or "not applicable". Here is sample data.

```
      Hostname      Status
      LOG            Open
      LOG           Not Applicable
      NETMAN         Open
      HD             Open
      NETMAN        Not Applicable
      LOG           Not Applicable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$existsnotopen = $hostid -eq $data."Host ID" -and $_.Status -ne $data.Open
```

As far as I can tell from your script (without sample data): `$hostid` is a single value, ex. `$hostid = $_."Host ID"`, while `$data` is an array considering you use `-notin $data."Host ID"` in the line above.

A string will not be equal an array. Also, `$_.Status -ne $data.Open` will always be true since a single value (Status) will never be an array (`$data.Open`).

**UPDATE**: This would also fail since there's nothing called `$data.Open`, `Open` is a `Status`-value.

Try:

```
$existsnotopen = @($data | Where-Object { $hostid -eq $_."Host ID" -and $_.Status -ne "Open" }).Count -gt 0
```

Comment: `$hosted` is a string so I see why I cant use `-eq`. I changed it to `-match`.
I used `$data."Host ID"` because I wanted it to search the whole spreadsheet like I did in `-notin $data."Host ID"`. I tried using what you tried because my status are either "Open" or "not applicable".     I added the sample data

Comment: sorry I meant to say it didn't work for me. Maybe because of `$status -ne $_.Status`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to define `$status` in he sample. Now that we know the status you're looking for, try the updated answer. There is nothing called `$data.Open`... Your sample is still incomplete. You never defined `$hostid`, we can only assume that this is inside a loop etc.

Comment: I defined it a little earlier in the script using  `$hostid=Read-Host "Please enter Hostname"`
I really appreciate your help... it did work for me.